# pg_restore: error: error returned by PQputCopyData when restoring database to heroku

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have my local database and I created a dump file that is 1.1GB I need that data to put on Heroku but every time I run this command

```
 pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h heroku-host -U db-heroku-username -d db-name dumpfile
```

my internet connection slows down and after few minutes I get following error
pg_restore: error: error returned by PQputCopyData: server closed the connection unexpectedly
This probably means the server terminated abnormally
before or while processing the request.
I don't know the reason I suspect that my internet connection is too weak to transfer data but nothing else comes to mind. Also, I saw that on the Heroku site number of rows stays the same about 16.9k but the size of the data changes.
This is the last line before the error:

```
pg_restore: processing data for table "public.stock_app_stock"
```

I tried changing commands and also made a few dump files with different configurations but the problem is the same always.

Comment: Check if the database version of dump source and database version of heroku db are the same.

Comment: Look at the database server logs.

Comment: @vicki I check they are both 14.7 version problem still persist

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I tried looking with heroku logs -p heroku-postgres -a myapp but nothing was displayed, they tried heroku logs -p heroku-postgres -a myapp --tail while running pg_restore on another terminal but still nothing showed up

Comment: One thing to note is that I tried restoring old database with far less data and it worked fine, Is it possible it's up to dump file or size of dump file

Comment: It could be a server crash or some network component breaking off the connection. If there is nothing in the server log, it is probably the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that database was big and the internet connection was not good to handle the data transfer between my DB and Heroku PostgreSQL DB also it helped when I upgraded Postgres DB to standard0